# Pattern matching using decorators

Tags: spring-mvc, decorator, sitemesh

I want to define a specific URL pattern using Sitemesh decorators.xml.  I want to define a decorator that matches all URLs ending with `"/story/_NUMBER_"` to be targetted by the decorator. I tried:

```
 <decorator name="customMain" page="customMain.jsp">
        <pattern>/story/[0-9]+</pattern>
 </decorator>
```

But this does not work.. Do regular expressions work in decorators.xml? If not, how do I target URLs that end with the above pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ran into this myself. I don't think it's possible to use regular expressions at all. Only wildcard patterns with * and ?.

Look at the [source](https://xwork.dev.java.net/source/browse/sitemesh/src/java/com/opensymphony/module/sitemesh/mapper/PathMapper.java?rev=1.3&view=markup) here for more details.